# Example of typescript + nextjs with required props properties?

Tags: typescript, next.js

Trying to use `@zeit/next-typescript` for some required props properties.

Have added it according to instructions [here](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-typescript).

Here's my component `tag.tsx`:

```
interface Props {
  itemName: string
}
export default function Tag(props: Props) {
  return <span className="tag">{props.itemName}</span>
}
```

I'm trying to define that `props` should have a property called `itemName` of type `string`.

Am aware that `strictNullChecks` is off by default, so I tried passing in a `number` instead, `<Tag itemName={1}/>`. But I don't get any errors.

Am I using it right?

Btw, is adding `"strictNullChecks": true` the way to turn it on?

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "es2016"]
  }
}
```